DJANGO [WinError 10061] email features
I'm working in a Django project that uses the mail features.
When try to send the mail I got this error message:
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
I'm using an email with godaddy domain.
This is my configuration:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtpout.secureserver.net'
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'

I have tried all the related questions like:
How to fix ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] the target machine actively refused it? (Django e.mails)
I checked the firewall and none of the ports like 587, 25, 465, etc. were blocked.
I also tried to connect with office365 server and didn't work.
I'm running it in my local machine, port 8000 is listening.
I have disabled firewall.
I don't know if this worth, but I have errors connecting with some pages for example when I run pip install library, gives an error related to SSL certification and only works if I bypass with --trusted-host. Maybe in this case I need to use something similar.

Check your system clock time and date.
